# How to Parse and Combine More than 10 RSS Feed into one array using Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, rss

Im trying to implement a Feature into My Project using Swift that Parses and Combines more than 10 Feed into one array and displaying it into a UITableView. The Array of RSS Links will come from a CoreData Entity that contains all the info about the RSS Feeds like title of the Feed, link, Description,pubDate and enclosure RSS URL. But I Dont know how to parse each RSS URL and Combine them into an Array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the 'Stack Overflow Question Checklist' in the following link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist.
Basically, you need to show what have you done for solving this problem in terms of code, so as to get answer quick

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

- `URLSession` and `URLRequest`
- `JSONDecoder` and `Codable`